# How to remove a position property inherited from element.style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position, sidebar

I need to remove the automatic `element.style` `position:relative`property that is being applied to my Bootstrap generated `div`. If I make the element style to `static` it works fine.

[image: how to not apply the position relative from element.style]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how it was configured in the first place I would resort to JavaScript:

```
<script>
// Listen to the DOM load event before modifying the dynamic div
// As per @Rene van der Lende's contribution
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init_func)
  function init_func () {
    var troubledDiv = document.getElementById('mCSB_1_container')
    troubledDiv.style.display = "unset"
  }
</script>
```

Unless you can change the config before bootstrap gens your code, this would be the way to override inline style.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not able to find this div: It evaluates to null!! Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: @Lazafq From the sound of it, it seems you need to wait until the document has been loaded before modifying the inline style with something like: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",some_init_func);` and put the code of Sydney Y in `some_init_func()`. Your image shows it really is there....

Comment: Excellent guys !!! Thank fixed it. I do not have CS background so learning the ropes.....I am actually an electrical engineer...

Comment: @Lazafq there you go, glad to been able to help out. Be careful though, JS can get you zapped in the blink of an eye...

Comment: Thanks @Rene van der Lende, I totally overlooked that.

Comment: @Lazafq if this works, be nice and hit the 'accept answer' button to grant Sydney Y his reputations. Others will know what answer to choose when they com accross a similar problem...

Comment: @Lazafq Warning: pls read up on [Window: DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) on MDN as you might need a `load()` eventlistener instead of `DOMContentLoaded`. `DOMContentLoaded` does not wait for externals to fully load, while `load` does. Carefully consider pros/cons!!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to do this by JavaScript, as this is a dynamically generated element - I guess from the malihu jquery scroller.
Why don't you simply add !important to your css:

```
<style>
    div#mCSB_1_container {
        position: unset !important;
        top: unset !important;
        left: unset !important;
    }
</style>
```